# How to reset telerik dropdownlist control value on client side

Tags: telerik

I want to reset dropdownlist selection on clear button click and set default message.

```
 <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="radDrpDwn_User" runat="server" Width="325px" DefaultMessage="--select--">
 </telerik:RadDropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all there isn't any control in telerik called (RadDropDownList) , the compatible control is RadComboBox control
so you define it using the Following ;

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="radDrpDwn_User" runat="server" Width="325px" DefaultMessage="--select--">
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

and in the clear Button :

```
protected void Clear_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
radDrpDwn_User.ClearSelection();

}
```

regards

Comment: If ClearSelection not worked then try this : radDrpDwn_User.Items[0].Selected = true;